# Как закешировать видео в браузере?

Tags: html5, кэширование, браузер

Подскажите, как можно закешировать видео для фона сайта в браузере, что б каждый раз не загружать его?

Answer (score 0):

При первой загрузке страницы видеофайл сохранится в кэше браузера посетителя и при повторном посещении будет проигрываться непосредственно из кэша. Это будет продолжаться до тех пор пока посетитель не очистит кэш браузера, либо на странице не обновится видео.